# How to get gmail full screenshot

Tags: gmail, screenshot

I'm trying to get full screenshot of HTML mail on Gmail.

Chrome extensions which like [Screen Capture (by Google)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-capture-by-google/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg)  does't work enough.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

You'll not be able to take the complete screenshot of an email in Gmail default window. You need to take a different route to accomplish this i.e.

1. Click on the Print, it will open a new tab with Print dialogue.
2. Close/Cancel the Print dialogue (don't close the new tab).
3. Use [Nimbus Screenshot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nimbus-screenshot-and-scr/bpconcjcammlapcogcnnelfmaeghhagj?) or any other extension to take the screenshot of the HTML email.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Screen Capture by Google doesn't work for a long time. I recommend you [Nimbus Screenshot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nimbus-screenshot/bpconcjcammlapcogcnnelfmaeghhagj?hl=en-US). It is also a Chrome screenshot extension. And I just used it to get a full screenshot of HTML mail on Gmail. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried everything with Nimbus but it simply wont work. Fragment Area takes the entire screenshot but only the visible part is saved rest image is blank.

Instead try clicking on the 'Print' icon on the upper right corner of your mail and save it as PDF.